# How to assign id zero while selecting the default in dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a drop Down list and I want that if the user selected nothing the id should be stored in database as 0, other wise if the user selected something then the id of that item is stored.
Code is here:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {

       Query = @"SELECT [category_id] FROM [Category_Master]";
       ds1 = dl.fetchrecord(Query);
       ddl_parent.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---none---"));
       int i = 0;
       while (i < ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
       {
           flag = 1;
           catname = "";
           index = 1;
           ListItem li = new ListItem();
           li.Text = catmapping(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["category_id"].ToString());
           li.Value = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["category_id"].ToString();
           ddl_parent.Items.Add(li);
           i = i + 1;
    }
   }
   lbl_mess.Text = "";
}


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   if (IsPostBack)
   {
       Query = @"INSERT INTO [RbmDatabase].[dbo].[Category_Master]
      ([Category_ParentId]
      ,[Category_Name]
      ,[Category_MetaTag]
      ,[Category_MetaTagKeywords]
      ,[Category_Description]
      ,[Category_SortOrder]
      ,[Category_Status]
      ,[Category_UpdateDate])
VALUES ('" + dl.QoutesHandel(ddl_parent.SelectedValue.ToString()) + "','" + dl.QoutesHandel(txt_category.Text.Trim()) + "','" + dl.QoutesHandel(txt_MTdesc.Text.Trim()) + "','" + dl.QoutesHandel(txt_MTkey.Text.Trim()) + "','" + dl.QoutesHandel(txt_Desc.Text.Trim()) + "','" + dl.QoutesHandel(txt_order.Text.Trim()) + "','" + dl.QoutesHandel(ddl_status.SelectedIndex.ToString()) + "','" + String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", DateTime.Now) + "')";
       dl.insertrecord(Query, lbl_mess);
       lbl_mess.Text = "Record Inserted  Successfull.....!";

   }

}
```

Comment: What result are you getting at the moment? `ddl_parent.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---none---"));` should give you a list item with ID of 0 that will be stored in your database...

Comment: here in drop down list when i am selecting none then data is not inserting in database but if i am selecting any item then that is storing in database proper with it's ID

Comment: Is there a foreign key relation involving the Category_ParentID? If so, does the value 0 exist in the parent table? I'm guessing that's where the error comes from.

Comment: no no it's only one table and there is no foreign key here ?

Comment: Sorry I missed something, in my first comment the insert is *not* inserting an item with ID 0. For that you should use the code from @Qboid

Comment: you are not getting my point if i am selecting none the value is not stored in database  if i select any item that is stored with it's id .?

Comment: `ddl_parent.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---none---"));` will give you a list item without a value, only a text property
`ddl_parent.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---none---", "0"));` will give you a list item with a value of 0. Look in the html markup that you get and you should see the difference

Comment: thanks  a lot for this solution i have wasted 2-3 hrs on this code.but i always failed one more thing sir when i am selecting status enable or disable it is not storing properly ((see the code for status) i have written ddl_parent .selectedindex.to string is not working .@ Simon Martin

Comment: You should mark Qboid's answer as the answer to your original question. That will help anyone else coming to this see that the problem is solved and what the answer was. As for the ddlStatus... there is nothing in the code that shows how you are assigning the values. Could it be a similar cause to the ddl_parent issue, if not consider creating another post to ask that question

Answer (score 2):

You should insert the "none" value when creating the list item

```
new ListItem("---none---", "0"));
```